# I disabled mDNSResponder and now can't use Firefox, but can connect through Opera (Chromium based)

Tags: macos, security, dns

I'm trying to harden my macOS, and have read that mDNSResponder has some vulnerabilities, so I disabled it (after disabling SIP, then restarted with SIP turned on). 
So now I can't connect to Internet. Though, when I'm trying to browse with Firefox I can connect only to google.com. My other apps also can't connect.

But with Opera browser I can connect to any site! As I could assume it's related to Google DNS thing.

So currently I have these questions, could you please help with any of them if you know something:

**1) Why Opera has a connection? It means that Opera always use Google DNS even if I don't put 8.8.8.8 or similar into my network settings? Means it's kinda have some potential 'spy' abilities?**

**2) Is there a way to have mDNSResponder disabled and have a possibility to have a net?**

Comment: *What* vulnerabilities are you referring to that necessitated you disabling mDNSResponder?  As for Opera, they could be using [DNS over HTTPS](https://bit.ly/2UVSvhG) (DoH) so it's nothing nefarious per se.  As or spying, anything you send to servers you don't control can technically spy on you,

Comment: mDNSResponder handles *all* DNS lookups on macOS for the system resolver, not just multicast DNS, disabling it will break most network functions on macOS. Programs that do not use the system resolver, like `host`, `dig`, `nslookup`, and (apparently) Opera will still be able to look up names, but that's all.